# How to combine perfect forwarding with brace enclosed initializers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding, list-initialization

This code compiles:

```
pair <pair<int,int>,unique_ptr<int>> t({0,0}, unique_ptr<int>());
```

As well as that:

```
tuple<pair<int,int>,unique_ptr<int>> t(make_pair(0,0), unique_ptr<int>());
```

But this one does not:

```
tuple<pair<int,int>,unique_ptr<int>> t({0,0}, unique_ptr<int>());
```

The reason is that the third one calls `tuple(const Types&...)`, but it seems like an arbitrary limitation.

Is C++11 unable to express this with variadic templates or is it possible?

Comment: A constructor of `std::tuple<T...>` taking `T...` would do the job. Such a constructor results in one construction + one move for non-reference types (meaning one extra copy construction for those types without move constructors), one construction more than what we have.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but not trivially.  To make this work, a tuple containing `N` arguments has to support `2^N` constructors, all combinations of `T&&` and `T const&` for each `T`.

What we have to do is to mix in these `2^N` constructors which can be done using inheritance. As constructors of base classes can only made available with `using` them explicitly, we can only add the constructors of a fixed number of base classes, so we have to use recursion.

One approach would be counting from `0` to `2^N` and make the ith parameter const-ref if the ith bit is 1 or an rvalue otherwise. Do this with `2^N` base classes in total where each one adds one constructor to their direct base.

```
namespace detail {
  // A bitlist holds N powers of two: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...
  template <std::size_t... i> struct bitlist { using type = bitlist; };
  template <std::size_t N, typename=bitlist<>>
  struct make_bitlist;  
  template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... i>
  struct make_bitlist<N, bitlist<i...>>
    : make_bitlist<N-1, bitlist<0,1+i...>> {};
  template <std::size_t... i> struct make_bitlist<0, bitlist<i...>>
    : bitlist<(1<<i)...> {};

  struct forward_tag {}; // internal struct that nobody else should use

  // if T is a reference, some constructors may be defined twice, so use a non-accessible type.
  template <bool B, typename T>
  using const_if_set = typename std::conditional<B,
    typename std::conditional<std::is_reference<T>::value, forward_tag, T const&>::type, T&&>::type;

  // Our helper class.  Each tuple_constructor is derived from N-1 others
  // each providing one constructor.  N shall equal (1<<sizeof...(T))-1
  template <std::size_t N, typename L, typename... T> struct tuple_constructor;

  template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... I, typename... T>
  struct tuple_constructor<N, bitlist<I...>, T...>
    :  tuple_constructor<N-1, bitlist<I...>, T...>
  { // inherit base constructors
    using tuple_constructor<N-1, bitlist<I...>, T...>::tuple_constructor;
    tuple_constructor(const_if_set<(N & I), T>... t)
      : tuple_constructor<N-1, bitlist<I...>, T...>
          (forward_tag{}, std::forward<const_if_set<(N & I), T>>(t)...) {}
  };

  // base case: N=0, we finally derive from std::tuple<T...>
  template <std::size_t... I, typename... T>
  struct tuple_constructor<0, bitlist<I...>, T...> : std::tuple<T...> {
    tuple_constructor(T&&... t)
      : tuple_constructor(forward_tag{}, std::forward<T&&>(t)...) {}

    // All constructor calls are forwarded to this one
    template <typename... T2>
    tuple_constructor(forward_tag, T2&&... t2)
      : std::tuple<T...>(std::forward<T2>(t2)...) {}
  };

  // Convenience using for N=2^n, bitlist=1,2,4,...,2^n where n = sizeof...(T)
  template <typename... T>
  using better_tuple_base = tuple_constructor
    < (1<<sizeof...(T)) - 1, typename make_bitlist<sizeof...(T)>::type,  T... >;
}

template <typename... T> struct better_tuple : detail::better_tuple_base<T...> {
  using typename detail::better_tuple_base<T...>::tuple_constructor;
};
```

[Live at LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1Kvsye%240)

But beware, this doesn't scale well to large tuples and increases the compile time significantly.  In my opinion, this is a limitation in the language.

Comment: There is another approach.  Type-erase constructing a `T`.  The constructor of this takes a `template<U> ctor(U&&)` and a (non-template) `ctor(T&&)`, and stores how to construct a `T` from its argument.  `{}` calls the `T&&` constructor, other stuff calls the `U&&` constructor.  Construction of the various fields must be done in non-typed memory (!), in a class that takes a type-erased constructor of conceptual type `void(void*)` from which it constructs its conceptual `T`.  More than a bit crazy, but avoids exponential blowup.  It may be difficult to optimize the run time cost away.